# Xamarin forms, Add new item to listview dynamically

Tags: xamarin.forms

I couldn't find a solution on the internet of how to add a new item to listview dynamically in Xamarin forms project when the button is clicked. The only things I got on the internet is how to delete an item from listview dynamically.

So please how I can write a code in Xamarin forms to add a new item to the listview dynamically when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 4):

if your List's ItemSource is an ObservableCollection, just adding an item to the collection should update the list

```
ObservableCollection<string> data = new ObservableCollection<string>();

data.Add("a");
data.Add("b");
data.Add("c");

myListView.ItemSource = data;
```

in your event handler

```
protected void MyButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs a) {
  data.Add("z");
}
```

Comment: I have found though that sometimes the ListView does not update on the UI when the List or collection values change at run time. I was able to resolve this issue by setting the ItemSource = null, then reassigning the ItemSource to the List.

Answer (score 3):

**in the code behinde of MainPage.xaml.cs, let say you have a class Person**

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

**and**

```
private ObservableCollection<Person> _persons;
public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
{
    get
    {
        return _persons ?? (_persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>());
    }
}
```

**In the click button event handler (code behind):**

```
private void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //create person here 
    var person = new Person()
    {
        Name = "toumir",
        Age = 25
    };

    //add the created person to the list
    Persons.Add(person);
}
```

**The MainPage.xaml Page look like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App2"
             x:Class="App2.MainPage">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0">
            <Button Clicked="Button_OnClicked" Text="Add Person"/>
        </StackLayout>

        <ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                         <StackLayout Margin="1">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Age}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                            <MenuItem Text="test"></MenuItem>
                        </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                        </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```